# Unix command to fetch n lines after the grep result in bash is not working when used in conjunction with awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am trying to fetch logs in between a timeframe, I was able to do it successfully with below command (though it gives the ideal result)

file.log 
2016-08-10 13:53:35 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused
2016-08-10 13:53:36 something blah blah blah

```
cat file.log\
  | grep "refused" \
  | awk -F, \
      -v b='`date --date="10 minutes ago" +"%F %T"`' \
      -v e='date +"%F %T"' \
      -v date="$(date +"%F %T")" \
      '{ if ($1 >= b && $1 <= e) print $0,date }'
```

Returns:
2016-08-10 13:53:35 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused

However, now to capture some more info about the error/exception I would like to have 3-5 more lines printed after the ERROR has happened to have an idea of type of exception,

Expected output:
2016-08-10 13:53:35 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused
2016-08-10 13:53:36 something blah blah blah

I am using:
    cat filename | grep -A 2 "refused" |
    awk -F, -v b='`date --date="10 minutes ago" +"%F %T"`' -v e='date +"%F %T"' \
        -v date="$(date +"%F %T")" '{ if ($1 >= b && $1 <= e) print $0,date }'

Returns: 
2016-08-10 13:53:35 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused

Using '-A 2' seems to have no effect on the output. Any suggestions??

NOTE: If I don't use awk, the below command works just fine as expected
cat filename | grep -A 3 "ERROR"

Comment: it's strictly the `grep -A 3 "ERROR"` that is not working as you expect. Not all `grep`s support `-A` option. What OS are you using? OR maybe you need `-A3` (no space)? AND of course, you don't need `cat`, just `grep stuff filename` will work too. Good luck.

Comment: [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you write the right script to do what you want rather than helping you put bandaids on the wrong script.

Comment: As my mentioned , only when I use -A 3 with grep, I am not getting the desired output. @shelter - grep -A is supported fr my OS, its linux.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
awk \
    -F, \
    -v b="$(date --date "10 mins ago" +"%F %T")"
    -v e="$(date  +"%F %T")" '
/ERROR|WARNING/ && ($1 " " $2)>=b && ($1 " " $2)<=e {print; cnt=5; next}
cnt>0 {print; --cnt}
' <filename
```

Notes:

- No need for `grep`, each time a match is found, set a counter to 5.
- Use counter to print 5 non-matching lines below each match.
- Your variable assignments look funny in the OP: some are double-quoted, some are single quoted. Only those of the type`-v var="$(date ...)"` will be run by the shell, those that look like `-v var='<backtick>...<backtick>'` will be passed to `awk` as literal strings, which is not what you want.
- I removed the extra `date` variable after edits to OP, because I don't see a need for that.
- The date and time will appear as `$1` and `$2` to awk. Before comparing to `b` or `e`, you need to cat those together as strings, separated by a space.

Comment: you can replace `cnt>0 {print; --cnt}` with `cnt&&cnt--`

Comment: @karakfa: and why would anyone want to make things even more obscure than they already are?

Comment: it's  not more complicated.  It's an idiom that can be learned,

Comment: @Matei : I am not just greping 'ERROR', but I have some more patterns to be greped. I am using something like grep "ERROR\|EXCEPTION\SOME MORE" | awk .....cmd....

Comment: The `awk` syntax would be `/ERROR|EXCEPTION|SOME MORE/` instead of only `/ERROR/`.

Comment: I tried this, awk -F, -v b='`date --date="10 minutes ago" +"%F %T"`' -v e='date +"%F %T"' -v date="$(date +"%F %T")" '{ if ($1 >= b && $1 <= e && /Connection refused/) print $0,date;cnt=5;next } cnt>0 {print;cnt--}' file.log
The result is same as earlier, no effect. Am I doing womething wrong?

Comment: The `b` and `e` settings are wrong, as single-quotes won't be expanded. So Awk will run with `b='<backtick>date --date="10 minutes ago" +"%F %T"<backtick>'`, which I doubt is what you want. So I assumed you meant `b="$(date...)"` instead (same for `e`), but then Awk would see `b='2016-08-11 00:45:17'`, including a space. In the OP, you seem to compare this with `$1`. I am not sure what you mean by that: what is `$1` in the input log? I didn't understand this part, that's why I left the variable settings up to you in the answer.

Comment: @Matei - As per my original post, the awk cmd works fine. I am trying to fetch the logs given a timeframe i.e. 10 minutes from the current time (b-e is 10 minutes). As per my log file $1 is date/time so I am comparing it whether it falls  in the range specified in if{} clause. Since grep returns only the matching lines, I wanted 3 more lines after the matching has happened.

Comment: @suraray see my comment under your question and do what it suggests if you'd like help.